# F# Async.FromBeginEnd not catching exceptions

Tags: asynchronous, f#, azure-table-storage

I'm having trouble working out why the following code doesn't catch the exception. It's my first go with Async in F# so I'm sure it's something simple

```
open System
open Microsoft.WindowsAzure
open Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient
open System.Windows.Forms

let mutable connection = "UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://ipv4.fiddler"

CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher(fun cName cPublisher ->
                                                      cPublisher.Invoke connection |> ignore)

let storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse connection

let createTable tableName =
        let client = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient()
        async{
            try
                do! Async.FromBeginEnd(tableName, client.BeginCreateTable , client.EndCreateTable)
                MessageBox.Show "Created" |>ignore
            with 
            | :? StorageClientException -> printfn "failed"; MessageBox.Show("failed to create table") |> ignore
            | _ -> printfn "Failed with unknown exception"
        } |> Async.Start

[<EntryPoint; STAThread>]
let main(args) =
    let form = new Form()
    let btn = new Button(Text = "Click")
    btn.Click.AddHandler(fun _ _ -> createTable "SomeNewTable")
    form.Controls.Add btn
    let result = form.ShowDialog()
    0
```

If I run this and the table has already been created it says that an exception of type StorageClientException was not handled in the code, specifically pointing at the client.EndCreateTable part of the FromBeginEnd call

Comment: Kind of a side issue, but if your exception handler were being called, it probably wouldn't be called from the UI thread, so that `MessageBox.Show` isn't a good idea where it is.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you replace `Async.Start` with `Async.RunSynchronously`?

Comment: yeah the messageBox is just there for testing at the moment. It'll be swapped out for a callback function later. Swapping for RunSynchronously doesn't change anything :(

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting? And do you have VS2010 SP1 installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Don Syme,
The solution is to turn off debugging "Just my code".
Debug -> Options and Settings -> General -> uncheck "Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)

This is still a problem with the Visual Studio 11 beta that came out with the Windows 8 consumer preview.

Comment: This is definitely *not* the solution. The only thing happening here is now the error is not being caught by the debugger when it occurs!

Comment: It seems to me that it's a problem with vs and F#. As a couple of people have said here it behaves as expected without the debugger attached. This solution allowed me to get back to work on the problem. It's not a "head in the sand" fix either akin to just ignoring the problem as it works at run time

Comment: By disabling Just My Code, you're also disabling the ability for VS to catch unhandled exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

This smells like an issue that was fixed in FSharp.Core in VS2010 SP1.  The .NET `SynchronizationContext`s changed their behavior (in .NET 4.0 SP1, I think), and we needed a corresponding change in the F# runtime for async's to properly deal with the thread affinity.

I think you can grab the newer FSharp.Core here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=15834

Comment: hmmmm unfortunately not. I've installed SP1, got the option to repair when I followed the link, and I see the same beahviour in Visual Studio 11 preview :(

Comment: I cannot repro this using @pad's repro on either my SP1 box or my Dev11 box.  Does that repro work for you?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>If the reason of the exception is that the table already exists, why not use `BeginCreateTableIfNotExist`/`EndCreateTableIfNotExist` instead.</strike>

**UPDATE:**

The bug has nothing to do with Windows Azure. I am able to reproduce the same behavior with a simple program:

```
open System
open System.Windows.Forms

let bufferData = Array.zeroCreate<byte> 100000000

let async1 filename =        
    async{
        try 
            use outputFile = System.IO.File.Create(filename)
            do! outputFile.AsyncWrite(bufferData)   
            MessageBox.Show("OK") |> ignore         
        with 
        | :? ArgumentException -> printfn "Failed with ArgumentException"; MessageBox.Show("Failed with ArgumentException") |> ignore         
        | _ -> printfn "Failed with unknown exception"; MessageBox.Show("Failed with unknown exception") |> ignore         
    } |> Async.Start

let main(args) =
    let form = new Form(Text = "Test Form")
    let button1 = new Button(Text = "Start")
    let button2 = new Button(Text = "Start Invalid", Top = button1.Height + 10)        
    form.Controls.AddRange [| button1; button2; |]
    button1.Click.Add(fun args -> async1 "longoutput.dat")
    // Try an invalid filename to test the error case.
    button2.Click.Add(fun args -> async1 "|invalid.dat")    
    let result = form.ShowDialog()
    0

let _ = main([||])
```

The strange thing is *the code works fine in F# Interactive but fails to catch exceptions when being debugged as a Windows application inside Visual Studio (not matter Debug or Release configuration). Even stranger, it works fine again if being executed as an application outside Visual Studio.*

In case you wonder, this program is adapted from [a MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370487.aspx) which exhibits the same issue.

**UPDATE 2:**

A similar question has been asked at http://cs.hubfs.net/topic/Some/0/59516. As @ildjarn and @Brian pointed out, this bug has been fixed in VS2010 SP1. Without VS2010 SP1, alternatively you can test your code using F# Interactive and execute the application outside VS without any problem.

Comment: well that's fine for this example, but what about other operations that are created from the FromBeginEnd construct, also that doubles the number of requests to the table service which for a high volume site can be a very bad thing indeed

Comment: Why would "create the table if it doesn't exist" double the number of requests over "create the table and throw an exception if it already exists"?

Comment: `CreateTableIfNotExist` can still throw `StorageClientException`; this is not an answer.

Comment: @JoelMueller I'm pretty sure that if you run the request through fiddler you'll see a get request followed by a create. But regardless ildjarn has the right of it. This is a hybrid app so I can't count on always being able to reach the table service

Comment: Thinking out loud, your update makes me wonder if the issue is due to the lack of a `SynchronizationContext` in the compiled application...

Comment: Your edit behaves _properly_ for me when running as a compiled application -- i.e., I get a messagebox reading "Failed with ArgumentException". What version of .NET are you targeting? And do you have VS2010 SP1 installed?

Comment: I'm using F# 2.0/.NET 4.0 but without VS2010 SP1 installed :)

Comment: @ildjarn: To be clear, have you debugged the application inside VS or executed it outside VS? Because it fails the first case, and runs fine in the second on my machine (see my update).

Comment: Both ways fail for me with my code in VS(11) and FSI. I've tried pad's example in VS 11 preview and it still doesn't catch the exception from within VS. From FSI however it does catch the exception. I have SP1 installed, but am primarily using 11 preview. Running without the debugger attached does behave as expected. Guess I'll just have to put my faith good old unit testing ;)